# Word or phrase to describe an activity that is "used to pass time"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-requests

Aside from *pastime*, what is a word or phrase that can be used to describe an activity that is not pleasurable and used only as a diversion while letting time pass?

Comment: Maybe _time killer_ or _distraction_ will work. I know that _TV_ fills that role for me.

Comment: *Killing time* works for me, too. Or *marking time*. *Watching the grass grow*. *Tracing cracks in the ceiling*. There was a whole [song](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DzpzbMLDliyI&ei=PSHsUJ39MemY2AWWr4H4CA&usg=AFQjCNF68yY-LaiYl7oFGHhCw9AgFqmJYQ&sig2=XipuLMzOTcmwj6g-TnGf4w&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.b2I) about this back in the 60s.

Comment: idling works for me

Comment: StackOverflow and its many cousins.

Comment: @Robusto Genius. Pure ingenuity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The noun "pastime" actually describes activity that is *pleasurable.*

> **pastime**
>
> an activity that someone does regularly for enjoyment rather than work; a hobby: his favorite pastimes were shooting and golf.

To describe an activity that is *used only as a diversion while letting time pass*, you can say you are doing something to **kill time**.

> **kill time**
>
> to do something which is not very useful or interesting while you are waiting for time to pass

Or you can just say you are **idling**, or, **lollygagging**.

> **lollygag**
>
> spend time aimlessly: he sends her to Arizona every January to lollygag in the sun.

Personally I don't think there is any word that describes an activity which is ***not pleasurable** and used only as a diversion while letting time pass* as when you want to kill time, you don't do things that are particularly ***not pleasurable***, but things that have no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

> Idling
>
> Twiddling your thumbs

Answer (score 0):

Nouns synonymous with pastime are few in number in English. Besides *lollygag,* the other suggestions here seem to be verbs. If you need a noun, I wonder if *timekill* or *time-kill* would work. In Indian English, time pass is a common noun.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase I hear all the time in the software industry is a "[**time suck**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=time%20suck)".  Especially in reference to meetings, which are also frequently referred to as "time wasters" which is essentially the same thing, *time suck* just sounds better.